# onClick event in navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have made a navigation drawer in Android in which I want to implement onClick for it. This is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle aToggle;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    aToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.navig, R.string.open, R.string.Close);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(aToggle);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.navig);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    aToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (aToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}}
```

This is my XML layout for the activity:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.alpit.formula2.MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/nav_action"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#EF6C00"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFA726"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationTheme">


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my menu items:

```
    <group
        android:id="@+id/gp1"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_maths"
            android:icon="@drawable/maths"
            android:title="Maths" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_physics"
            android:icon="@drawable/physics"
            android:title="Physics" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_chem"
            android:icon="@drawable/chem"
            android:title="Chemistry" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/EEE"
            android:icon="@drawable/lightbulb"
            android:title="Electronics Electrical" />
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/gp2"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/unitconversion"
            android:icon="@drawable/unitconversion"
            android:title="Unit Conversion" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Scientist"
            android:icon="@drawable/scientist"
            android:title="Scientist" />


        <item
            android:id="@+id/favourite"
            android:icon="@drawable/favourite"
            android:title="Favourite" />
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/gp3"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Share"
            android:icon="@drawable/share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Rate"
            android:icon="@drawable/rate"
            android:title="Rate" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ads"
            android:icon="@drawable/ad"
            android:title="Remove Ads" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/aboutus"
            android:icon="@drawable/aboutus"
            android:title="About Us" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

The problem is I am not able to understand how to implement the `onClick` on the navigation drawer as it is populated by the list given by us not by any listView.

How can I implement `onClick` on the items of navigation drawer?

Comment: `as it is populated by the list given by us not by any listView` could you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Sorry i know this line would bug, after implementing the navigationView i scanned many tutorial about them, they all were populated by a listView, by that they could easily get the location of the item clicked. Thats why i added this line.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to add ***implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

**and add method**

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

       case R.id.nav_maths: {
      //do somthing
            break;
        }  
    }
    //close navigation drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

**method to set Listener**

```
private void setNavigationViewListener() {
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

**call method in onCreate()**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setNavigationViewListener()
}
```

Comment: Can u tell how to implement onClickListner in this ?

Comment: It is more helpful and working fine in my project. Thanks.

Comment: What if the click is actually on the header of the menu? I'm trying to capture a click on the avatar in the header and not a menu item.

Comment: Somehow it is not calling the item selected even after added all code.

Answer (score 5):

Add **NavigationItemSelectedListener** event to **nav_view**

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Implement your Activity with **NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener**

and add this code for click item

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am not using framgents,so do i have to implement this method in every activity or there is any other way for it Thanks.

Comment: Yes you have to create navigation view and write same to for every other activity. But it is not best practice. Use fragment it will good for u to achieve ur task

Comment: Sorry for late reply,but nothing is happening when i does it.

Answer (score 2):

> Below code is for adding toggle to DrawerLayout

```
 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
 drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
```

And to add listener to Navigation menu items

```
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

and override below method

```
@Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id. nav_maths){
      //Handle your stuff here
    } 
}
```

> Add below code to onCreate method

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: Nothing is happening when i does it.

Comment: You have missed returning a boolean and closing the drawer.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val nav_view: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    nav_view.bringToFront();
}
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when(item.itemId){
        R.id.miid_log_out -> Toast.makeText(this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return false
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

in your

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (aToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}}
```

add these lines:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.nav_maths:
        // your logic here.
        return true;
    case R.id.nav_physics:
        //your logic here
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1:** Extends the `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` on your Activity
**Step2:**
Then there will show an error then override the method:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        return false;
    }
```

get the Id with `menuItem.getId()` .And Perform Your Action as per your need.

**final Step:** Add This line in onCreate `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 binding.navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.book -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Booked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            true
        }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -6):

```
  fab=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
}
    }
```

Comment: Please add some context to as why this code works. That improves the quality of your answer! :)