# can't get a reference to menu item

Tags: android, android-studio, menu

I got my navigation menu and I can't activate a function when an item is being clicked on. I don't get any id on my log console. I have tied using `switch` and it didn't work. My menu can open perfectly. I hope someone will know how to fix it.

```
public class SummeyAct extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_summey);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this ,drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        context = this;
    }
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        Log.d("menu id",String.valueOf(item.getItemId()));

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.PlayerListMenu:
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Players.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.FanChatMenu:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, Players.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                return true;
            case R.id.SighnOutMenu:
                LogOutMethod();
                return true;


        }
        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Does "onOptionsItemSelected()" ever get called?

Comment: Do you have these id's defined in your menu.xml?

Comment: yes my id is defind

Comment: i dont know how to call it, but whan i open the navigation ber the toast is working but the id equals to ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` on your navigation view and get the callbacks on click on there.
[Check out answer on this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297381/onclick-event-in-navigation-drawer)

Comment: i didnt fully anderstand what you ment

Comment: You are using navigationView in your xml. Right?

Comment: yes but i didnt understand what should i write there

Comment: You need call setNavigationItemselectedalistener on that and handle on click on items there. Check out the link I posted. It should be sufficient.